# Difference in browser rendering/positioning for CSS triangle vs unicode

Tags: html, css

I'm showing a triangle next to some text inside of a container with `display:flex`. The text's width is not known at design time. The browser will calculate the width needed for it upon rendering. I've provided code below which highlights my scenario.

The issue I'm encountering:

- On initial render `.triangle-two`'s position is not correctly determined. The browser appears to not know the width of `.text` quite yet and so it incorrectly positions `.triangle-two` until a second rendering pass occurs. Just a moment after rendering `.triangle-two` shifts to its correct position.

By contrast, `.triangle-one` does not exhibit this issue at all. I presume that this is because `.triangle-one` is rendered as text, and thus in the same pass as `.text` where as `.triangle-two` is rendered at a different point-in-time making it ineligible for the proper positioning.

Of note, if I apply `justify-content: flex-end` to `.container` then this issue does not occur because `.triangle-two` is positioned first and then `.text`. So, it's a non-issue when going the other direction.

Is this a common problem? Are there any more elegant solutions?

**Note:** I'm unable to reproduce the issue with my example provided, but I'm unsure why. I feel confident that this example highlights my issue, but perhaps it's also dependent on page initialization.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.triangle-one {
  transform: scale(1, .5);
}
.triangle-two {
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='text'>
    Dynamic text
  </div>
  <div class='triangle-one'>▼</div>
  <div class='triangle-two'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out the next day.

The issue is that I have no text on the page on initial load and then append a bunch of views to the page which have text on them. I'm also using a custom font face.

Since there's no text on the page on initial load - the font face isn't loaded when the views are appended. So, the text shifts around once its font loads causing its shape to change. Then, the triangle next to it needs to reposition.